# Eclipse Subversive "Connection Failed By Server"

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using Eclipse Indigo and Subversive SVN Team provider.

While i was generating projects using SVN repository i provided user name and password.

Now after a week i want to update some files,
right click on a file, Team->Update, getting below error:

```
Some resources were not updated.
svn: connection refused by the server
svn: PROPFIND request failed on 'bla bla'
```

I think i must log in but from where, can you provide a path? Or what may the problem be?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PROPFIND request failure probably means, Subversive cannot read contents from the server. A more detailed error message **might** be present in the Error log view (Window/Show view/Other..., and there it is in the General category, if I remember correctly).

Without a more detailed error message I would open the SVN Repository Exploring <del>view</del>perspective, and try to update the Repository location settings (Right click, Properties), and there try to (1) validate the existing settings, and (2) update the username/password information.

Comment: what do you mean by "open the SVN Repository Exploring view", perspective?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant the perspective.

Comment: Thanks @ZoltánUjhelyi !! I was using repository with ip adress and network admins changed the server ip adress without notifying me, Now I will switch to use the server by its DNS name ;)

Answer (score 9):

Just open eclipse preferences.
click on <kbd>General</kbd>><kbd>Network Connections</kbd>.

Then according to the environment, set active provider and other proxy settings.

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse preferences. click on <kbd>General</kbd>><kbd>Network Connections</kbd> -> change `Active Provider` value to `Manual` from the drop down. it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps allow me to work from my corporate network through proxy server to update Eclipse ide plugins, and connect to corporate svn server:
1. Open Window > Preferences > Network Connection Settings
2. Select Active Provider to "Manual"
3. Set proxy settings for HTTP/HTTPS (click Edit…)
4. Clear SOCKS proxy if it is set (select SOCKS row, click "Clear" button)
5. Add host svn.srv.com in Proxy bypass if svn.srv.com is within intranet
6. Apply and optionally restart Eclipse

Note: replace proxy.srv.com, and svn.srv.com with your actual urls
See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338212/eclipse-kepler-not-connecting-to-internet-via-proxy?answertab=votes#tab-top) also

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your eclipse network setting , 
add SVN server to bypass proxy list

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse preferences. click on General>Network Connections -> change Active Provider value to Manual from the drop down. it worked for me too.