# Eclipse Kepler not connecting to internet via proxy

Tags: eclipse, proxy, eclipse-kepler

I have managed to get Eclipse Juno connecting to the internet. For this to accomplish, there are many posts here on stackoverflow. here is one of this links:
[Eclipse not connecting to internet via proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539681/eclipse-not-connecting-to-internet-via-proxy)

Today i installed Eclipse Kepler on my Windows7 box. But accessing the eclipse marketplace or installing new software does not work.
I am using exactly the same proxy configuration as i used for Eclipse Juno. Juno can access the marketplace but Kepler does not.
The proxy uses NTLM Authentification.
Any one here with similar problem?

No success til now. I am still wondering why Juno can connect whereas Kepler can not:-(

Comment: For me Firefox was the problem, I put Chrome by default and no more problem with both marketplace and install new software. I didn't change the network connections parameters.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question :) After searching a lot on google with no luck finally I got the solution here on SO.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

I had same issue. I searched and found this.

http://oakgreen.blogspot.jp/2011/10/eclipse-proxy-settings-bug-and.html

This post says don't set SOCKS proxy. I tried this advice, and connection was succeeded.
I did below:

1. Open Network Connection Settings.
2. Select Active Provider to "Manual".
3. Set HTTP/HTTPS proxy.
4. Clear SOCKS proxy if this is set.(select SOCKS proxy row and click "Clear" button)
5. Restart Eclipse to apply these settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had to do this for Eclipse Juno. There it works. But for Kepler it does not. When you use manual mode all three boxes are checked (http,https,socks) I am not able to uncheck SOCKS. But i have cleared the input fields

Comment: Three check box are all checked after clear SOCKS config. As you mention, I have been able to connect through proxy when I used Juno and Indigo although all proxy config are set. It's an enigma...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As mentioned by cho above, I couldn't uncheck the SOCKS proxy but clearing it using the 'Clear' button was sufficient to connect over the proxy.

Comment: I have been able to connect through proxy for Eclipse kepler. I have mentioned proxy for http, https only, configuration is host, port, domain\user (as user), password and marked checked 'Required Authentication' checkbox. It works.

Comment: Pleas note that Eclipse needs to be restarted after clearing the socks settings.

Comment: Solved my problem too

Comment: @user1708042, it worked without restarting in Eclipse Luna. Btw I find it amazing how badly designed this particular GUI (proxy settings) is. The checkbox is totally confusing and a sane user will face the weird question "If I press CLEAR and all the chekboxes are checked will this clear all fields for all protocols or just the one that I've selected".

Comment: Same problem with Mars. Totally agree with you @rbaleksandar

Comment: Still a valid answer as of 2017 with Eclipse Oxygen

Answer (score 7):

I spent hours trying to use this method suggested by mhanada and although it is correct and should have worked the default Secure Storage associated with eclipse was preventing my proxy credentials from being saved. I advise: Be wary of exceptions being thrown regarding Secure Storage. In my case the errors related to being unable to connect to a remote location where the default secure storage path was. In my case I just deleted the Default Secure Storage information via Preferences > General > Security > Secure Storage > Contents > Delete.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I set it to "**native**" settings where socks was enabled for proxy. (**Internet Explorer->Internetoptions->Connections->LAN-Settings->Proxy Settings**). After disabling it there and adding the following lines to eclipse.ini everything works well:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=3000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=3000
```

Comment: +1 It is THE solution. I have written the similar http://stackoverflow.com/a/34204939/715269, with a reference. You could include it here, too.

Comment: I still included the manual proxy settings and authentication due to me being behind a proxy.

Comment: I believe this is required if the user is using an NTLM proxy.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem started after installing the Spring Tool Suite. Uninstalling it solved the problem.

Version: Kepler Service Release 1

Answer (score 2):

A friend of mine ran into that exact problem (fresh machine with a fresh eclipse Kepler installation, the computer was not behind a firewall or proxy.) It turned out to be an issue with Java 7 update 51, when we used a Java 6 JRE to run eclipse the problem was magically solved.

Answer (score 2):

Another note:

After changing my Windows password, eclipse's Windows-integrated secure storage seemed to have become inaccessible without notice. Apparently this not only made eclipse 'forget' my proxy auth settings but also prevented it from storing the credentials after I set them up again. I could configure them any way I wanted but as soon as I clicked "OK" they were gone again.

The solution for me was to go to General > Security > Secure Storage and click on "Change Password..." for the Windows Integration master password provider. Of course, this wiped all passwords previously stored by eclipse, but it left me with a clean, working Secure Storage and allowed me to successfully set up and store the proxy credentials again.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me **because eclipse was using JRE and not JDK**.

To force eclipse to use a given VM, edit

```
<eclipse_root>\eclipse.ini
```

and add those 2 lines at the top of the file:

```
 -vm
 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javaw.exe
```

Note:
Eclipse using JRE was triggering a:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket**

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:274)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:797)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket cannot be found by org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.1.3.v201209201135
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem , The issue with my set up was I was using JDK, after repointing to JRE it is working perfectly now.
Proxy Setup- Windows->Preferences->General->Network Connections.
Active Provider-Native, Just make sure HTTP - Dynamic should be checked, remaining all should be Unchecked.

Note: Above Description Tried and tested with Kepler only.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that you selected the `Manual` mode in the `Active Provider` section? Go to the `Preferences`**/**`General`**/**`Network Connections` menu again and change that if it is not. I think that part is kind a buggy.

Comment: Yes, this was already essential for configuring Eclipse Juno. As stated above, i used the same config for Juno

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and i changed the proxy settings with password in eclipse.
go to **windows-> preferences->** search for "proxy"
open **Network connections**.

Select Active Provider to **Manual**.
Set HTTP and HTTPS proxy, system **username** and **password**.
(it was not working without username and password in my machine)

Clear SOCKS proxy if its set.

**File-> Restart**