# Couldn't load Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I use Eclipse Kepler on Windows 8. When I open Eclipse Market place, its progressing bar still remains in the same place. I have proper internet connection. What might be the problem? Help me.. I couldn't install any new plugins..

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess would be your firewall is blocking the access to the marketplace. That's not unusual, especially on business computer. Fortunately, there is an alternative. Go to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/ and select the plugin you need. Then drag the "install" icon and drop it in your Eclipse window. Normally, it should install the plugin.

Comment: It also gives the same effect!

Comment: I think you have a problem with you network connection. Is it your company's computer or a personal? Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857499/how-do-i-have-to-configure-the-proxy-settings-so-eclipse-can-download-new-plugin

Comment: personal computer. I use mobile broadband internet provider's network.

Answer (score 0):

add the following two lines in start of /eclipse.ini

-vm
C:/Program Files/Java//bin/javaw.exe

also change

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion <(JDK version you are using)1.8>

Now it works...!

I used the answers in the following thread...

[Eclipse Kepler not connecting to internet via proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338212/eclipse-kepler-not-connecting-to-internet-via-proxy)

thanks guys!