# Java Runtime Environment 8 doesn't support <E> mechanism

Tags: java, eclipse

is not supported by Java Runtime Environment 8. What is the alternative way to achieve it?

I tried to create heap using `ArrayList` as follows:

```
ArrayList<E>list = new ArrayList<E>(length);
```

It doesn't work. Eclipse requested to change JRE environment to an older version...

Comment: Eclipse will uses Java 2 SE 4 by default. This is a problem within Eclipse support for Java 8, not with Java 8 per se.

Comment: What release of Eclipse are you using? Kepler or Luna or something else?

Comment: If you are using Kepler, there is a update site here:http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3-P-builds  I tried this and updated my Eclipse, and build support is added.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Kepler

Comment: When I tried to use install new software, it says unable to read the depository. I disabled firewall. I followed many instructions from web to achieve it. Still I couldn't fix it. Even Eclipse marketplace progressive bar remains unchanged after middle way. My internet connection is good. But not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for now you have to manually add Java 8 support since the latest offical version of eclipse doesn't yet support Java 8.

Instructions are here:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/java8/

Comment: I have the following unsolved problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015382/couldnt-load-eclipse-marketplace-in-eclipse-kepler